# How to run command after ssh connection?

Tags: ssh

When I connect remote I always run

```
cd ~/w/logs
tail -f some_file.log
```

but when I do

```
ssh host 'cd ~/w/logs; tail -f some_file.log'
```

all is OK, but after CTRL+C the connection is lost. ([similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/79645/ssh-run-a-command-on-login-and-then-stay-logged-in) question, but does not cover CTRL+C problem)

How to run command after remote login?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do two things. The first is to run interactive bash after the tail will exit (the `bash` in the end) and then you need to allocate remote TTY so the session will become interactive (`-t` switches):

```
ssh -t host 'cd ~/w/logs; less +F some_file.log; exec $SHELL'
```

`exec` -- If  command  is  specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created

Comment: Nope. This does not work. When I press CTRL+C to stop 'tail' command the connection is broken. I have try this: ` ssh -t sv "cd ~/w/logs; exec bash -l -c tail -f psgi.log"` but without success ((

Comment: Ok,  Ctrl+C, kills all session. Considering some commands that you don't have to kill (`less`) will work for you (will update answer).

Comment: have you mispell, the man does not describe `-tt`, only `-t`?

Comment: No: "Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.". It is not this case, but I am somehow used to do that in similar cases. But for clarity I removed them :)

Comment: Does it possible to limit CTRL+C only to the commands in the chain? for example command long run and I want to stop it but without session interuption.

Comment: It might be, but I didn't find the way to do it properly. Ctrl+C is caught by the remove shell (which runs under the command you wrote on the commandline.

Comment: I just don't understand why you don't write your commands in the profile of your login shell and just start a simple ssh without any commands to run remotely.

Comment: I have some ideas `ssh -t host 'cd ~/w/logs; bash; exec $SHELL'`. in the first bash I can press CTRL+C and connection is not broken. Also I can run `tail -f some_file.log` and CTRL+C, but when I `bash tail -f some_file.log` instead of just `bash` I got "/usr/bin/tail: cannot execute binary file"

Comment: @GombaiSándor Because for each connection I run different commands.

Comment: I see, I just took "When I connect remote I always run..." literally.