# After ssh login to server, have custom .profile run and modify shell environment

Tags: ssh

### Preamble

I work in an environment with a lot of servers and developers. The servers are all generally set up for ease of use, so we all log into a common account. These are internal-only servers, so security is not a large concern. Most devs, myself included, add their public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I would like to have my usual environment customisations available after logging in.

### What I do currently manually

```
studog@doghouse:~# ssh example.local
common@example:~# . ./studog_profile
common@example:~#
```

I'd like to have this occur automatically instead.

Extra credit: I'd like to always push my current `.studog_profile` and so I always have my current customisations available.

Ideally:

```
studog@doghouse:~# ssh example.local
common@example:~#
```

and `.studog_profile` has already been sourced and my customisations are available.

### Constraints

- My `.studog_profile` contains environment variable setup including
  PATH changes, aliases and function declarations.
- I can push uniquely-named files to servers (and modify `.ssh/authorized_keys`) but I can't change common configurations like `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
- I often ssh from my doghouse, but often ssh between servers. A
  solution needs to work in both situations. I don't expect to be able
  to push my custom profile between servers though.

### Things that don't work

- `ssh -t example.local '. ./.studog_profile; bash -l'`. This does run
  my profile, but then the environment changes are lost when the login
  shell runs.
- Altering `.bashrc` on the servers. See the constraint above about
  altering common configurations. Nevertheless, I could probably get
  away with it, but, ssh doesn't provide a way to see what the 'start
  of the ssh pipe' is. `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` contain the IP
  address of the originating server for the current hop, but there is
  nothing containing the identity of the machine on which I'm typing.

### Questions I've read that don't work for me

- [Run ssh and immediately execute command - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522647/run-ssh-and-immediately-execute-command)
  [How to run command after ssh connection? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1047148/how-to-run-command-after-ssh-connection)
  These use `bash -l` which loses changes.
- [Can I ssh somewhere, run some commands, and then leave myself a prompt? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301917/can-i-ssh-somewhere-run-some-commands-and-then-leave-myself-a-prompt)
  Top answer shows how to inject environment variables but not aliases
  or functions. Also my profile is quite large, and this looks
  unwieldy.
- [How can I run a script immediately after connecting via SSH? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/how-can-i-run-a-script-immediately-after-connecting-via-ssh)
  Alters common configuration, which I might get away with but only
  works for the 'from the doghouse' not 'between servers' situations.

### Things I haven't tried

- [SSH, run a command on login, and then Stay Logged In? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/79645/ssh-run-a-command-on-login-and-then-stay-logged-in)
  An expect script is often mentioned. I believe that would work. It
  just seems...  hacky? inelegant? the wrong solution? Something rubs
  me the wrong way.

### Expectation

ssh has some method for sending a post-login command to the remote server, likely a keyword in `~/.ssh/config`. I haven't been able to find anything. I find this strange because accepting keyboard input and sending it to the remote server is nearly the same as reading a command from the config file and sending it to the remote server.

I have to think this is missing because it's a security hole, but I can't see what that hole might be.

I expect I could modify OpenSSH source and build what I need, but that's time consuming. Also, if it's a security hole my pull request is likely to be ignored.

I expect that I have covered all the bases. I'm posting in the hopes I've missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An expect script is often mentioned. I believe that would work. It just seems... hacky? inelegant? the wrong solution? Something rubs me the wrong way.

Hacky environment require "hacky" solutions. If you would have properly configured servers with your personal user, with shared home, you would be able to configured this in once place and it would work everywhere out of the box.

If you have bunch of servers with a single user used by bunch of devs, where one can not make its own changes, you have to work around it in your computer and in that case, expect script is probably a way to go.

Comment: That's what I figured. I hoped for better. Thanks!

Comment: Rereading your answer, I'm going to take issue with the "shared home" setup. That's good if you have a few servers that people will often log into. It's a huge waste of space of you have many servers that any single authorized person may only log into once, or never. Which is my situation. The servers in question also have very limited storage space. :-(